# Merging two repositories with different folder structure and preserving the file's history from both

Tags: git, merge, salesforce, bitbucket

I have two repositories, an old one, call it 'Old', created 5 years ago with the last commit on 18th May 2021, and the 'New' one created on 15th April. Both are hosted on BitBucket.
These repositories have different file structures, although all the files I care about are in the folder with the same name `classes`. In the Old repo, they are in `oldRoot/project-atm/src/classes`, in the New one in `newRoot/atm-app/main/default/classes`:

```
oldRoot
  |_project-atm
  |    |_src
  |         |_classes
  |             |_(files with the history I need to get)
--------

newRoot
  |_atm-app
  |    |_main
  |         |_default
  |             |_classes
  |                 |_(files that should see the old history)
```

Besides these, there are a bunch of different folders, I put a screen down below.

I'd like to 'combine' the Old repository into the New one so I'd be able to see the `git blame` or check the history of the files up to the very beginning 5 years ago, right now I have to switch between the repos when I need.

I tried creating a third repository and using the commands below, but I did not get the history, probably because I have not put anything about the directory there:

```
git clone --bare newRepoUrl
git push --mirror thirdRepoUrl

git fetch newRepoUrl/project-atm/src/devfix/ devfix
git merge -s ours --no-commit FETCH_HEAD --allow-unrelated-histories
```

To Salesforce people that may read this - we wanted to switch our legacy project to DX structure but were unable to do it, so we created a New repository with proper structure and just retrieved everything from the orgs, and now I would like to have the old history combined.

[image: Old Repo Sctructure]

[image: New Repo Structure]

Comment: Interesting question! Have you tried https://ntotten.com/2018/05/11/convert-metadata-to-source-format-while-maintain-git-history/ ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "file history" in Git: there are only commits, which *are* the history. So what you need is to arrange the commits, e.g., by splicing these together with `git replace`. You might want to rewrite the old history into the new structure before doing the splicing.